# Zip file cannot be opened in third party app

Tags: android, zip, android-fileprovider

I'm trying to load a zip file which is downloaded into `context.getFileDir()` into third party application

The result from the third party is " *No files are selected * " i have tried to check if the zip file is downloaded successfully so i have unzipped it from the code and it seems that it's downloaded properly and it should be opened in external third party application.

I have putted Provider into manifest in order to export the URI

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                tools:replace="android:resource"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
```

And my path

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="internal" path="." />
</paths>
```

And this is how what im trying to do

```
File file = FileHelper.GET_FILE(material);
                try {
                    unzip(file);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(material.getContext(), material.getContext(). 
getApplicationContext().getPackageName() +
 ".provider", file);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/zip");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        material.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: What should that unzip(file) statement do? It is unclear with what you want to feed the third party app. The zipped file? The unzipped file?

Comment: Why do you still start an intent when you do have that exception?

Comment: @blackapps the unzip method is just for making sure that the zip file is valid and it is valid
the intent is for letting the device to choose the zip reader so that i created an intent tp put the uri 
is there any way to open that file without intent? i don't want to create an internal reader

Comment: If the unzip call throws an exception then why do you still continue to start an intent? I asked that before!!

Comment: You should add a flag Intent.FLAG_READ_URI_PERMISSION. (Or something like that) Then it should work. Ha ha i see that you answered already yourself..

Comment: @blackapps the unzip working properly

Answer (score 0):

It seems that i forgot to add this flag to the intent

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

after adding this flag everything works properly